# Extracting elements from cell array based on data type

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm loading qxf data into MATLAB using the function `qxf2mat`. This creates the following 1x1 struct:

```
struct with fields:

                 qxfName: 'BSR1786214'
        numberOfChannels: 14
          numberOfCycles: 24477
          parameterCodes: {1×14 cell}
          parameterTitle: {1×14 cell}
     parameterShortTitle: {1×14 cell}
     parameterDefinition: {1×14 cell}
    minimumObservedValue: [1×14 double]
    maximumObservedValue: [1×14 double]
             absentValue: [1×14 double]
                datetime: [24477×20 char]
                BTVOLTCM: [1×24477 single]
          BTVOLTCM_flags: {1×24477 cell}
                HEADCM01: [1×24477 single]
          HEADCM01_flags: {1×24477 cell}
                ISCMBMA1: [1×24477 single]
```

What I want to do now is extract all the [1x24477 single] elements and put them into their own matrix. So the matrix would have 24477 rows, and in this example, 3 columns.

I've used `struct2cell` to convert the struct into a cell array, and was planning to use `cell2mat` after that, but I can't because of all the different data types.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier just to access them by name? Or do the names change?

Comment: The names change from dataset to dataset, so ideally I just want to access them with indexing.

Comment: Do you know the size beforehand, or do you get it from `numberofCycles`?

Comment: Only get it from numberOfCycles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is a way of doing it:

```
% Get the names of the fields
fnames=fieldnames(mystruct);

% Get the fields that are both not a cell, and the correct size
thisones=~structfun(@iscell,mystruct)&structfun(@(x)(size(x,2)==mystruct.numberofCycles),mystruct);

% to make sure they are always 3 (else the struct is different of what you showed)
assert(sum(thisones)==3);

%Get the index of the fields
indices=find(thisones);

% make a matrix by appending the columns
result=zeros(3,mystruct.numberofCycles);
for ii=1:3
   result(ii,:)=mystruct.(fnames{indices(ii)});
end
```

Note that this will not work if you have 2 structures with size 1xN that are different types, but are not a cell. You would need to make the `thisones` condition more complex.

Comment: Okay, so for my complete example I have 14 columns (instead of 3), and this is indicated by the numberOfChannels parameter. I tried replacing 3 with 14 in your code, but the last step fails with: 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions'. Should I also change the size(x,2) part?

Comment: @BradReed if it fails then it must be because you haven't replaced it in `result=zeros...` or because it did not find 14 fields

Comment: Breaking the code down, and running for just one of the indices, say `ii=14`, the `fnames{indices(14)}` works but it gives the error when trying to run `mystruct(fnames{indices(14)})`.

Comment: @BradReed what is `size(indices)`? 13? Then it has only found 13 fields. But I cant debug without the real case

Comment: No, its 14. Yes I know, sorry, I appreciate it's harder without the data.

Comment: @BradReed if size(indices) is 14, how does `mystruct(fnames{indices(14)})` return error? what is the value of `indices(14)`? and the size of `fnames`?

Comment: `indices(14)` is 38, which is correct, and `size(fnames)` is 39

Comment: Then how can this error?? @BradReed There is nothing out of bounds

Comment: I think the problem is coming from `mystruct('HEADCM01')`. Should I be using `mystruct.'HEADCM01'` ? This is using index 2 in this example I posted originally.

Comment: @BradReed there was a typo, try now

Comment: That's fixed it. Thanks a lot for your help!